# BeautifulSoup help, how to extract content from not proper tags text in html file?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<tr>
<td nowrap> good1 </td>
<td class = "td_left" nowrap=""> 1 </td>
</tr>

<tr0>
<td nowrap> good2 </td>
<td class = "td_left" nowrap="">  </td>
</tr0>
```

How to using python parse it? please help.
I want to get the result as list ['good1',1,'good2',None]

Comment: You mention BeautifulSoup; have you looked at its documentation? If you could try adapting some of those samples to suit your needs and then come back for help if you’re not quite getting the right output, that would make it easier for us to give a useful answer.

Comment: Yes, I read the document. but actually I want to do it as soon as possible, and also the question is just a part of my project. Really is difficult for me, I worked it for two days now, and console  appeared warning many times . You konw, learn something is quitely difficut, so I come for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find all `tr` tags and get all `td`s from it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = """<tr>
<td nowrap> good1 </td>
<td nowrap class = "td_left"> 1 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td nowrap> good2 </td>
<td nowrap class = "td_left"> 2 </td>
</tr>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
rows = soup.body.find_all('tr')
print [td.text.strip() for row in rows for td in row.find_all('td')]
```

prints:

```
[u'good1', u'1', u'good2', u'2']
```

Note, [strip()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) helps to get rid of leading and trailing whitespaces.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, but python console appeared this warning: ArrtibuteError: 'Resultset' object has no attribute 'td'. and the question I edited just few minutes ago.

Comment: @coolahao ok, I've replaced `row.td` with `row.find('td')` - please check.

Comment: warning happened again. ArrtibuteError: 'Resultset' object has no attribute 'find'.

Comment: @coolahao are you running the exact concrete piece of code I've provided?

Comment: @alexce, I listed a bit of html content in the question. I checked the type of my rows is <class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>.

Comment: @coolahao are you sure you have this line `print [row.td.text.strip() for row in rows]`?

Comment: @alexce, you are right. I type rows instead of row. so the problem appearing. thanks.

Comment: @alexce， but the result only give [u'good1', u'good2']， not  ['good1',1,'good2',None].

Comment: @coolahao ok, why do you think there should be `None` in the list?

Comment: @alexce, please consider the None as 2. <td class = "td_left" nowrap=""> 2 </td>
</tr0>, will you help me fix it? the destiny result is  ['good1',1,'good2',2]

Comment: @alexce, I will check it later. Now it seems exhausting much memroy and cpu of my computer.

Comment: @alexce, maybe there is some little inperfect in your code, because I exectue the script your supplied to me, the computer almost can't run.  my parsed file size is not big than 40 kb.